# How to produce a distinct count of records that are stored by day by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with several "ticket" records in it.  Each ticket is stored by day (i.e. 2011-07-30 00:00:00.000) I would like to count the unique records in each month by year I have used the following sql statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   YEAR(TICKETDATE) as TICKETYEAR,
   MONTH(TICKETDATE) AS TICKETMONTH,
   COUNT(DISTINCT TICKETID) AS DAILYTICKETCOUNT
FROM
   NAT_JOBLINE
GROUP BY
   YEAR(TICKETDATE),
   MONTH(TICKETDATE)
ORDER BY
   YEAR(TICKETDATE),
   MONTH(TICKETDATE)
```

This does produce a count but it is wrong as it picks up the unique tickets for every day.  I just want a unique count by month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combining Year and Month into one field, and grouping on that new field.
You may have to cast them to varchar to ensure that they don't simply get added together. Or.. you could multiple through the year...

```
SELECT    
   (YEAR(TICKETDATE) * 100) + MONTH(TICKETDATE),
   count(*) AS DAILYTICKETCOUNT
FROM    NAT_JOBLINE GROUP BY
 (YEAR(TICKETDATE) * 100) + MONTH(TICKETDATE)
```

Comment: Feel free to re-introduce the columns  YEAR(TICKETDATE) and MONTH(TICKETDATE), if you want them to still be brought back. It shouldn't affect the group by... just make sure to add them to both the select and group by clauses.

Comment: Lynn--Please see the above comments, this is still picking up some dupes and I am really perplexed on how it is!

Comment: I did cast these as a varchar and it made no difference just so you know

Comment: Count(*) is going to count the lines not unique values.  Max did you test the answer I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that `TICKETID` is not a primary or unique key, but does appear multiple times in table `NAT_JOBLINE`, that query should work. If it is unique (does not occur in more than 1 row per value), you will need to select on a different column, one that uniquely identifies the "entity" that you want to count, if not each occurance/instance/reference of that entity.

(As ever, it is hard to tell without working with the actual data.)

Comment: What I am trying to find is every unique ticketid that occurs in the table for a single month.  The problem is that is a single month the ticketid can occur several times (like once every day).  So if that tickeid occurs lets say every day in a month (30 times) it is still a unique count of one.  So far I have not found the correct statement

Comment: So far my supervisor has come up with a count of 1389 and his count is correct when I run the above query I get a count of 1770 so I am thinking that I am still picking up some dupes somewhere.  How is my question

Comment: Toss in `COUNT(TICKETDATE)`, see how that differs from the DISTINCT count. I really don't see anything wrong with your query, this is straight-forward stuff. I suspect there is something else going on here -- triggers, views, changing data, sunspot activity, something like that.

Comment: I am feeling that way myself--I think I just need to keep tweaking this query as I feel it is giving me the correct results.  I am marking it as the answer.  I will see if I can get to the bottom of things  Thanks again.

Comment: OH MAX !! Hello !!  Did you test my answer ???   Is see something wrong with Maxes query - a superfluous DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the first distinct. You already have the group by.  If I was the first Distict I would be confused as to what I was supposed to do.

```
    SELECT 
      YEAR(TICKETDATE) as TICKETYEAR,
      MONTH(TICKETDATE) AS TICKETMONTH,
      COUNT(DISTINCT TICKETID) AS DAILYTICKETCOUNT
    FROM NAT_JOBLINE
    GROUP BY YEAR(TICKETDATE), MONTH(TICKETDATE) 
    ORDER BY YEAR(TICKETDATE), MONTH(TICKETDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your comments to Phillip Kelley's solution:

```
SELECT TICKETDATE, COUNT(*) AS DAILYTICKETCOUNT
FROM  NAT_JOBLINE
GROUP BY TICKETDATE
```

should do the trick, but I suggest you update your question.

Comment: That will produce a total count by day.  He wants a count of unique by month.